# How much current can float through all pads of the PDB (Power distribution board)?

Tags: flight-controller, esc, brushless-motors, batteries, ardupilot

I want to buy the „PDB-HEX, 12S“ Power Distribution Board. Are the current values of **PDB/current sense resistor** and **ESC power pads** meant for the summarized current of all motors or for each Motor? Why is the current sense resistor value higher than the esc power pads current?

PDB:

- Input voltage range: 6~60V (2~12S LiPo)
- **PDB/current sense resistor**: 140A cont, 264A burst.
- **ESC power pads**: 60A cont. 100A burst
- 6x ESC power /signal/ telemetry pads
- Current Senor: 264A,  3.3V ADC
- Current Scale 125(INAV/BF),  BATT_AMP_PERVLT  80 (ArduPilot)

For Example:

I want to use this brushless motor with this specifications:
[image]

When I use 4 of these motors I have a total max. current of 39.56*4=158.24A.

If the PCB-values "**ESC power pads**: 60A cont. 100A burst" are for a single pad it would fit but if it is for all motors it wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the board, but current sensing is generally the total for all motors, which would explain why it's higher.

Current telemetry is usually used so you can gauge battery use, so you want the total.

The 'ESC power pad' figure is likely per-ESC as each ESC has its own set of pads. This limit is more than a quarter (or sixth) of the total because the highest loads occur when a motor is stalled by an obstruction, and that's rarely all motors at the same time.

Comment: so the "ESC power pads: 60A cont. 100A burst"-value is for all 4 connections/motors in sum?

Comment: I edited the question for a better understanding. Thank you for your answer!